# How to properly restore save game of ETS2 on macOS?

Tags: macos, euro-truck-simulator-2

I have all files from

`/User/myusername/Library/Application Support/Euro Truck Simulator 2`.

But there is a question. There are empty `profiles` folder, `steam profiles`, and some game version `steam profiles` folders. Which folder(s) am I supposed to copy and paste to (which) directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to restore a complete profile, you need to place it inside of the `profiles` folder (if you want to enable Steam Cloud for that profile, you can always change the option from the game menu).

For individual savegames on the other hand, you need to paste them in:

- No Steam Cloud: `~/Library/Application Support/Euro Truck Simulator 2/profiles/<Your Profile>/save`
- Steam Cloud: `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/<Your ID>/304730/remote/profiles/<Your Profile>/save`

Comment: “profiles” folder is empty. I don’t get what you are saying.

Comment: I guess that you have either a Profile or Savegame that you want to install/restore (you are literally asking for "Which folder(s) am I supposed to copy and paste to (which) directory?"). If you are not looking for this, you need to rephrase your question because is too broad.

Comment: It is not broad even though your response does not make any sense since the folder is empty.